# dcast summarise on single column

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, reshape2

I would like to pivot my data so I can get the average survival rate using dcast, but it seems like it may not be possible:

**Data**

```
PassengerId Survived    Pclass  Name    Sex Age SibSp   Parch   Ticket  Fare    Cabin   Embarked
1   0   3   Braund, Mr. Owen Harris male    22  1   0   A/5 21171   7.25        S
2   1   1   Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer) female  38  1   0   PC 17599    71.2833 C85 C
3   1   3   Heikkinen, Miss. Laina  female  26  0   0   STON/O2. 3101282    7.925       S
```

code for sample data:

```
df <- structure(list(PassengerId = 1:6, Survived = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                  2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
                        Pclass = c(3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L), Name = c("Braund, Mr. Owen Harris", 
                                                                     "Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)", "Heikkinen, Miss. Laina", 
                                                                     "Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)", "Allen, Mr. William Henry", 
                                                                     "Moran, Mr. James"), Sex = c("male", "female", "female", 
                                                                                                  "female", "male", "male"), Age = c(22, 38, 26, 35, 35, NA
                                                                                                  ), SibSp = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Parch = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                  0L, 0L, 0L), Ticket = c("A/5 21171", "PC 17599", "STON/O2. 3101282", 
                                                                                                                                                                          "113803", "373450", "330877"), Fare = c(7.25, 71.2833, 7.925, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  53.1, 8.05, 8.4583), Cabin = c("", "C85", "", "C123", "", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ""), Embarked = c("S", "C", "S", "S", "S", "Q")), .Names = c("PassengerId", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "Survived", "Pclass", "Name", "Sex", "Age", "SibSp", "Parch", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "Ticket", "Fare", "Cabin", "Embarked"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

## Function so far:

```
reshape2::dcast(titanic, Sex ~ ., mean)
```

Desired Output:

```
Row Label  Average of Survived 
Male       3.14156  
Female     3.14156
```

Currently, it returns this error:

```
     Sex  .
1 female NA
2   male NA
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(.value[0], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I think this was possible to do with the cast function in reshape, but is this possible to do with reshape2?

Comment: In your survived column, does 1 mean survived and 0 means didn't survive?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I would assume that you should be able to do this easily, but maybe its in data.table, and not reshape2

Comment: Could you please provide more rows of your data (especially for Sex and Survived)? I think others columns are not important for your calculation.

Comment: `dcast` is for pivoting into multiple columns usually (maybe always?). If you only need one column, use `DT[, mean(Survived == "1"), by=Sex]` or similar. If you're using reshape2 but not data.table, then there's still `aggregate` from base... or `tapply`.

Comment: @Frank Yeah I wanted to get more clarification on if you should be using a dcast for this, as it's very easy to do with pandas pivot tables, and seems like you could do with( from the reshape paper): cast(ffm, treatment ~ ., length)
  treatment (all)
1 2 3
1  1159
2  1157
3  1155

Comment: @Frank the reason I ask is that you can do the same thing with pandas, can dcast do something this eloquent: df.groupby('sex')[['survived']].mean()

Comment: It's a reasonable question. Yeah, not in dcast as far as I know (though I could be wrong). There's syntax like that in dplyr (which in many ways is a reshape2 replacement) and in data.table (which is an alternative).

Comment: yeah I was wondering if there is going to be new functionality in dplyr as an upgraded dcast, although the power of stringing together multiple commands is incredibly flexible.

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention, dplyr is part of a set of packages including tidyr. I don't use it, but its `spread` function may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you can indeed use dcast for this, but Survived was a factor, which was throwing an error, and you need to define which column you want to use as a value to compute on. Turns out the column order does not matter either, which is surprising.

```
df$Survived <- as.numeric(as.character(df$Survived))
reshape2::dcast(df, Sex~., mean, value.var = "Survived")
#     Sex .
#1 female 1
#2   male 0
```

Comment: When I run this code with the given `dput()` data it returns 3 warnings: `argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`. The result shows `NA` for female and male. This doesn't look like the expected result to me.

Comment: The dput code generates Survived as a factor variable. It needs to be converted to a numeric using this code, and it should work fine: df$Survived <- as.numeric(as.character(df$Survived))

Comment: @petergensler
Based on your answer, it means your expected result is 1 for female and 0 for male. If yes, it is different from the desired output in your question which is 3.14156 for both male and female

Comment: those numbers are simply placeholders, not what the expected result should be.

Answer (score 2):

What about trying it using `dplyr`?

```
library(dplyr)
output <-  df  %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Survived = as.numeric(as.character(Survived))) %>%  
  dplyr::select(Sex, Survived) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(Sex) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(average_of_survived = mean(Survived))
output
## A tibble: 2 × 2
#     Sex average_of_survived
#   <chr>               <dbl>
#1 female                   1
#2   male                   0
```

Comment: dplyr is definitely an option, I was curious to see if something this simple could be done using reshape2. It seems like you could in the past with the cast function.

Comment: When I run this code with the given `dput()` data it returns a warning: `argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`. And `output` has only one row: `1 female                  NA`. So it doesn't look like the expected result to me.

Comment: @UweBlock
Thanks Uwe. Please, check the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

This could be done with `dcast()` from the `reshape2` (or the `data.table`) package as shown by the [OP's own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43006352/3817004).

Without `dcast()`, you could do the aggregation directly with `data.table` as well:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Survived := as.numeric(as.character(Survived))][, mean(Survived), by = Sex]
#      Sex V1
#1:   male  0
#2: female  1
```

`df` is used as given by the `dput()` in the Q. Chaining is used to form a "one-liner".

An even more concise version of the above would be

```
setDT(df)[, mean(as.numeric(as.character(Survived))), by = Sex]
```

Comment: thank you so much for the solution! nice to know that this is possible with data.table

Comment: @petergensler, I'm glad you find the solution useful.